# The difference between try/catch/throw and try/catch(e)/throw e

Tags: c#, exception

What is the difference between

```
try { }
catch
{ throw; }
```

and

```
try { }
catch(Exception e)
{ throw e;}
```

?

And when should I use one or the other?

Answer (score 153, accepted):

The constructions

```
try { ... }
catch () { ... } /* You can even omit the () here */

try { ... }
catch (Exception e) { ... }
```

are similar in that both will catch **every** exception thrown inside the `try` block (and, unless you are simply using this to log the exceptions, should be **avoided**). Now look at these:

```
try { ... }
catch ()
{
    /* ... */
    throw;
}

try { ... }
catch (Exception e)
{
    /* ... */
    throw;
}

try { ... }
catch (Exception e)
{
    /* ... */
    throw e;
}
```

The first and second try-catch blocks are EXACTLY the same thing, they simply rethrow the current exception, and that exception will keep its "source" and the stack trace.

The third try-catch block is different. When it throws the exception, it will change the source and the stack trace, so that it will appear that the exception has been thrown from this method, from that very line `throw e` on the method containing that try-catch block.

Which one should you use? It really depends on each case.

Let's say you have a `Person` class with a `.Save()` method that will persist it into a database. Let's say that your application executes the `Person.Save()` method somewhere. If your DB refuses to save the Person, then `.Save()` will throw an exception. Should you use `throw` or `throw e` in this case? Well, it depends.

What I prefer is doing:

```
try {
    /* ... */
    person.Save();
}
catch(DBException e) {
    throw new InvalidPersonException(
       "The person has an invalid state and could not be saved!",
       e);
}
```

This should put the DBException as the "Inner Exception" of the newer exception being throw. So when you inspect this InvalidPersonException, the stack trace will contain info back to the Save method (that might be sufficient for you to solve the problem), but you still have access to the original exception if you need it.

As a final remark, when you are *expecting* an exception, you should really catch that one specific exception, and not a general `Exception`, ie, if you are expecting an InvalidPersonException you should prefer:

```
try { ... }
catch (InvalidPersonException e) { ... }
```

to

```
try { ... }
catch (Exception e) { ... }
```

Answer (score 35):

The first preserves the stack trace while the second resets it. This means that if you use the second approach the stack trace of the exception will always start from this method and you will lose the original exception trace which could be disastrous for someone reading exception logs as he will never find out the original cause of the exception.

The second approach might be useful when you want to add additional information to the stack trace but it is used like this:

```
try
{
    // do something
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw new Exception("Additional information...", ex);
}
```

There's a [blog post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/perfworld/how-can-i-throw-an-exception-without-losing-the-original-stack-trace-information-in-net) discussing the differences.

Comment: Well that's great stuff to know!

Comment: so why use the second  then ? 
is it better to use only the first one?

Comment: The second comes in handy when you need to check for specific exceptinons - OutOfRangeException comes to mind - or need to log the message, etc. The first seems to be a wildcard exception handler similar to try{}catch(...){} in c++.

Comment: David, that only applies to the catch __(Exception e)__ part. And that is separate from `throw` vs `throw e`.

Answer (score 6):

You should use

```
try { }
catch(Exception e)
{ throw }
```

if you want to do something with the exception before re-throwing it (logging for example). The lonely throw preserves stack trace.

Comment: and what will happen if i replaced the "throw" here with a "throw e"?

Answer (score 5):

The difference between a parameterless catch and a `catch(Exception e)` is that you get a reference to the exception. From framework version 2 unmanaged exceptions are wrapped in a managed exception, so the parameterless exception is no longer useful for anything.

The difference between `throw;` and `throw e;` is that the first one is used to rethrow exceptions and the second one is used to throw a newly created exception. If you use the second one to rethrow an exception, it will treat it like a new exception and replace all stack information from where it was originally thrown.

So, you shold not use either of the alternatives in the question. You should not use the parameterless catch, and you should use `throw;` to rethrow an exception.

Also, in most cases you should use a more specific exception class than the base class for all exceptions. You should only catch the exceptions that you anticipate.

```
try {
   ...
} catch (IOException e) {
   ...
   throw;
}
```

If you want to add any information when rethrowing the exception, you create a new exception with the original exception as an inner exception to preservere all information:

```
try {
   ...
} catch (IOException e) {
   ...
   throw new ApplicationException("Some informative error message", e);
}
```