# Difference between 'throw' and 'throw new Exception()'

Tags: c#, .net, exception

What is the difference between

```
try { ... }
catch{ throw }
```

and

```
try{ ... }
catch(Exception e) {throw new Exception(e.message) }
```

regardless that the second shows a message.

Comment: The second snippet is one of the most evil (but innocuous) lines of code I've ever seen.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22623/net-throwing-exceptions-best-practices

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a difference between "throw" and "throw ex"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/730250/is-there-a-difference-between-throw-and-throw-ex)

Answer (score 357, accepted):

`throw;` rethrows the original exception and preserves its original stack trace.

`throw ex;` throws the original exception but resets the stack trace, destroying all stack trace information until your `catch` block.

## *NEVER* write `throw ex;`

`throw new Exception(ex.Message);` is even worse.  It creates a brand new `Exception` instance, losing the original stack trace of the exception, as well as its type.  (eg, `IOException`).
In addition, some exceptions hold additional information (eg, `ArgumentException.ParamName`).
`throw new Exception(ex.Message);`  will destroy this information too.

In certain cases, you may want to wrap all exceptions in a custom exception object, so that you can provide additional information about what the code was doing when the exception was thrown.

To do this, define a new class that inherits `Exception`, **[add all four exception constructors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182151.aspx)**, and optionally an additional constructor that takes an `InnerException` as well as additional information, and throw your new exception class, *passing `ex` as the `InnerException` parameter*.  By passing the original `InnerException`, you preserve all of the original exception's properties, including the stack trace.

Comment: "throw new Exception(ex); is even worse.": I disagree on this one. Sometimes you want to change the type of an exception, and then keeping the original exception as inner exception is the best you can do. Though it should be `throw new MyCustomException(myMessage, ex);` of course.

Comment: @0xA3: I meant `ex.Message`, which _is_ worse.

Comment: In addition to implementing the standard constructors, one should also make custom exceptions `[Serializable()]`.

Comment: Yes; I forgot to mention that.

Comment: I guess it depends. Sometimes you know what the cause of the exceptions is and still want to hide the details of your implementation from the user. This way, you pass the message (which you know is okay) and make it seem like you were the source.
Then: What 0xA3 said.

Comment: @Markus: **No**. _No No NO!_. _Always_ pass `InnerException`.  It makes it infinitely easier to track down a problem if you know exactly what the exception came from.

Comment: Yo dawg, we herd you like exceptions so we put an exception in yo’ exception so you can catch while you catch.

Comment: @SLaks: When you `throw;` the actual line number where the exception occurred is replaced by the line number of `throw;`. How do you suggest handling that?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493779/wrong-line-number-on-stack-trace

Comment: That means I can never [*throw up*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/549611)?? I have always wanted to *throw up* in my code :-(

Comment: downvoting because throw; doesn't always preserve the stack trace, as Eric mentioned.

Comment: to follow-up on @DirkVollmar,  if your code is sensitive and contains intellectual property or other sensitive data in the inner messages, you may intentionally want to mask any and all details of the inner exceptions in the api you expose.  In this case throw new MyCustomException(myMessage) makes sense without providing the inner exception.

Answer (score 46):

The first preserves the original stacktrace:

```
try { ... }
catch
{
    // Do something.
    throw;
}
```

The second allows you to change the type of the exception and/or the message and other data:

```
try { ... } catch (Exception e)
{
    throw new BarException("Something broke!");
}
```

There's also a third way where you pass an inner exception:

```
try { ... }
catch (FooException e) {
    throw new BarException("foo", e);
}
```

I'd recommend using:

- the first if you want to do some cleanup in error situation without destroying information or adding information about the error.
- the third if you want to add more information about the error.
- the second if you want to hide information (from untrusted users).

Answer (score 14):

One other point that I didn't see anyone make:

If you don't do anything in your catch {} block, having a try...catch is pointless.  I see this all the time:

```
try 
{
  //Code here
}
catch
{
    throw;
}
```

Or worse:

```
try 
{
  //Code here
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    throw ex;
}
```

Worst yet:

```
try 
{
  //Code here
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    throw new System.Exception(ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: I agree, unless you have the finally clause.

Comment: @ToniRossmann In this case I'd use try..finally without the catch, unless you're doing something other than throw;

Answer (score 14):

None of the answers here show the difference, which could be helpful for folks struggling to understand the difference.  Consider this sample code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ExceptionDemo
{
   class Program
   {
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
         void fail()
         {
            (null as string).Trim();
         }

         void bareThrow()
         {
            try
            {
               fail();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
               throw;
            }
         }

         void rethrow()
         {
            try
            {
               fail();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
               throw e;
            }
         }

         void innerThrow()
         {
            try
            {
               fail();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
               throw new Exception("outer", e);
            }
         }

         var cases = new Dictionary<string, Action>()
         {
            { "Bare Throw:", bareThrow },
            { "Rethrow", rethrow },
            { "Inner Throw", innerThrow }
         };

         foreach (var c in cases)
         {
            Console.WriteLine(c.Key);
            Console.WriteLine(new string('-', 40));
            try
            {
               c.Value();
            } catch (Exception e)
            {
               Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Which generates the following output:

```
Bare Throw:
----------------------------------------
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at ExceptionDemo.Program.<Main>g__fail|0_0() in C:\...\ExceptionDemo\Program.cs:line 12
   at ExceptionDemo.Program.<>c.<Main>g__bareThrow|0_1() in C:\...\ExceptionDemo\Program.cs:line 19
   at ExceptionDemo.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\...\ExceptionDemo\Program.cs:line 64

Rethrow
----------------------------------------
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at ExceptionDemo.Program.<>c.<Main>g__rethrow|0_2() in C:\...\ExceptionDemo\Program.cs:line 35
   at ExceptionDemo.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\...\ExceptionDemo\Program.cs:line 64

Inner Throw
----------------------------------------
System.Exception: outer ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at ExceptionDemo.Program.<Main>g__fail|0_0() in C:\...\ExceptionDemo\Program.cs:line 12
   at ExceptionDemo.Program.<>c.<Main>g__innerThrow|0_3() in C:\...\ExceptionDemo\Program.cs:line 43
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at ExceptionDemo.Program.<>c.<Main>g__innerThrow|0_3() in C:\...\ExceptionDemo\Program.cs:line 47
   at ExceptionDemo.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\...\ExceptionDemo\Program.cs:line 64
```

The bare throw, as indicated in the previous answers, clearly shows both the original line of code that failed (line 12) as well as the two other points active in the call stack when the exception occurred (lines 19 and 64).

The output of the rethrow case shows why it's a problem.  When the exception is rethrown like this the exception won't include the original stack information. Note that only the `throw e` (line 35) and outermost call stack point (line 64) are included.  It would be difficult to track down the fail() method as the source of the problem if you throw exceptions this way.

The last case (innerThrow) is most elaborate and includes more information than either of the above.  Since we're instantiating a new exception we get the chance to add contextual information (the "outer" message, here but we can also add to the .Data dictionary on the new exception) as well as preserving all of the information in the original exception (including help links, data dictionary, etc.).

Comment: Not sure why this was voted down without comments, since it says basically the same thing as the top answer but with more details.

Answer (score 11):

Throwing a new Exception blows away the current stack trace.

`throw;` will retain the original stack trace and is almost always more useful. The exception to that rule is when you want to wrap the Exception in a custom Exception of your own. You should then do:

```
catch(Exception e)
{
    throw new CustomException(customMessage, e);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`throw` rethrows the caught exception, retaining the stack trace, while `throw new Exception` loses some of the details of the caught exception.

You would normally use `throw` by itself to log an exception without fully handling it at that point.

BlackWasp has a good article sufficiently titled [*Throwing Exceptions in C#*](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/CSharpThrowingExceptions.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

`throw` is for rethrowing a caught exception.  This can be useful if you want to do something with the exception before passing it up the call chain.

Using `throw` without any arguments preserves the call stack for debugging purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Your second example will reset the exception's stack trace. The first most accurately preserves the origins of the exception.

Also you've unwrapped the original type which is key in knowing what actually went wrong... If the second is required for functionality - e.g., to add extended information or rewrap with a special type such as a custom 'HandleableException' then just be sure that the InnerException property is set too!

Comment: Yeah, this is one of those questions where you have to write fast. ;)

Answer (score 1):

`Throw;`: Rethrow the original exception and keep the exception type.

`Throw new exception();`: Rethrow the original exception type  and reset the exception stack trace

`Throw ex;`: Reset the exception stack trace and reset the exception type

Answer (score 0):

If you want you can throw a new Exception, with the original one set as an inner exception.

Answer (score 0):

Most important difference is that the second expression erases the type of the exception. And the exception type plays a vital role in catching exceptions:

```
public void MyMethod ()
{
    // both can throw IOException
    try { foo(); } catch { throw; }
    try { bar(); } catch(E) {throw new Exception(E.message); }
}

(...)

try {
    MyMethod ();
} catch (IOException ex) {
    Console.WriteLine ("Error with I/O"); // [1]
} catch (Exception ex) {
    Console.WriteLine ("Other error");    // [2]
}
```

If `foo()` throws an `IOException`, the `[1]` catch block will catch the exception. But when `bar()` throws `IOException`, it will be converted to plain `Exception` and won't be caught by the `[1]` catch block.

Answer (score 0):

*throw* or *throw ex*, both are used to throw or rethrow the exception, when you just simply log the error information and don't want to send any information back to the caller you simply log the error in catch and leave.

But in case you want to send some meaningful information about the exception to the caller you use throw or throw ex. Now the difference between throw and throw ex is that throw preserves the stack trace and other information, but *throw ex* creates a new exception object and hence the original stack trace is lost.

So when should we use *throw* and *throw e*? There are still a few situations in which you might want to rethrow an exception like to reset the call stack information.

For example, if the method is in a library and you want to hide the details of the library from the calling code, you don’t necessarily want the call stack to include information about private methods within the library. In that case, you could catch exceptions in the library’s public methods and then rethrow them so that the call stack begins at those public methods.

Answer (score 0):

... and PLEASE, don't catch the base "Exception" class unless you ALWAYS end the catch clause with a "throw;", otherwise, you will swallow the event and its exception's details -- hiding it from any higher-level code's catch clause that may want/need to process it.  Try to catch a specific sub-class or set of sub-classes; e.g., catch "FileNotFoundException" and not the "Exception" base class.