# Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement

Tags: c#, sql

I wrote a program that connects to MS Access.  When I fill in the fields and add a new item to Access the program fails.  The exception is "Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement"

Here is the relevant code.

```
****************************************************************
AdoHelper.cs
****************************************************************

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace Yad2
{
    class AdoHelper
    {
        //get the connection string from the app.config file
        //Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Yad2.accdb
        static string connectionString = Properties.Settings.Default.DBConnection.ToString();

        //declare the db connection
        static OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);

        /// <summary>
        /// To Execute queries which returns result set (table / relation)
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="query">the query string</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static DataTable ExecuteDataTable(string query)
        {

            try
            {
                con.Open();
                OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(query, con);
                System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter tableAdapter = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(command);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                tableAdapter.Fill(dt);
                return dt;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// To Execute update / insert / delete queries
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="query">the query string</param>
    public static void ExecuteNonQuery(string query)
    {
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand command = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(query, con);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// To Execute queries which return scalar value
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="query">the query string</param>
    public static object ExecuteScalar(string query)
    {
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand command = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(query, con);  /// here is the Excaption !!!!!!!!!
            return command.ExecuteScalar();
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }
    }

}
}

****************************************************************************


****************************************************************************
DataQueries.cs
****************************************************************************
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;

namespace Yad2
{
    class DataQueries
    {

        public static DataTable GetAllItems()
        {
            try
            {
                string query = "Select * from Messages";

                DataTable dt = AdoHelper.ExecuteDataTable(query);

                return dt;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }


        public static void AddNewItem(string mesNumber, string title , string mesDate , string contactMail , string mesType , string Details )
        {
            string query = "Insert into Messages values(" + mesNumber + " , '" + title + "' , '" + mesDate + "' , '" + contactMail + "' , , '" + mesType + "' , '" + Details + "')";
            AdoHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(query);
       }

        public static void DeleteDept(int mesNumber)
        {
            string query = "Delete from Item where MessageNumber=" + mesNumber;
            AdoHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(query);
        }
    }
}
***********************************************************************************************
```

Why does the program fail?

Comment: "porgram"? "Accsses"? "excaption"?  You should use spell-checker.

Comment: [• **NEVER** write `throw ex;`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2999298/difference-between-throw-and-throw-new-exception/2999314#2999314).

Comment: @abelenky: For some people, english is difficult.  Hence the Edit button so we can help clean it up.

Comment: @Chris:  ESL authors in particular should use spell-checkers.  The computer does the spelling so we don't have to.

Answer (score 4):

When you put your string into the SQL, you get a invalid syntax.
This would happen if one of the strings contains a `'`.

You need to use parameters.

Also, your SQL contains `, ,`, which is invalid syntax.

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
INSERT INTO table (column1, column2, ...)
VALUES ('value1', 'value2', ...)
```

Comment: +1 I suspect this is the primary issue.  All of the columns should be explicitly defined when doing an insert.  Otherwise it's brittle and likely to blow up when a DDL change occurs.

Answer (score 1):

```
string query = "Insert into Messages values(" + mesNumber + " , '" + title + "' , '" + mesDate + "' , '" + contactMail + "' , , '" + mesType + "' , '" + Details + "')";
```

yields

```
Insert into Messages
values(
    <number> , 
    '<title>' , 
    '<mesDate>' , 
    '<contactMail>' , , 
    '<mesType>' , 
    '<Details>'
)
```

Notice the two commas after  with a space between them.  This is not valid SQL.  You will also have a bad query if `mesNumber` is a null value in your code.

As Joe White commented with his link to XKCD #327, *always* sanitize your database inputs!  That means that if a string is passed to your method, you must escape all single quotes.

As SLaks commented, *never* use `throw ex;`, just use `throw;`

Comment: No; just remove the `catch` block entirely.

Comment: How right you are, SLaks, I never realized we could leave out the `catch` block.  For those interested, here is what Microsoft says about it: "There are three possible forms of try statements: A try block followed by one or more catch blocks. **A try block followed by a finally block.** A try block followed by one or more catch blocks followed by a finally block." source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664733(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply print out the value of `query` (to the debug window, console, message box, log file... wherever!), in `AddNewItem`, then examine the message.  It really should become clear then.