# What method of EF 6 is better to use for get data from database async?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have next code

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<MyTabel>> GetData()
        {
            try
            {
                var dbCtx = new myEntities();

                return await dbCtx.MyTabel.ToListAsync();
                //return await dbCtx.MyTabel.ToArrayAsync();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

I am wondering what is ToListAsync or ToArrayAsync method is better for perfomance  ?
does anyone know ?

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

for me performance is equal to less memory usage, faster query times, higher concurrency

Comment: [Never write `throw ex`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2999314/34397).  Get rid of the catch block.

Comment: "better" is very subjective here. What defines "better performance"? Less memory usage? Faster query times? Higher concurrency? You need to be a lot more specific about what you're trying to optimise for.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`ToList()` is faster than `ToArray()`, because the array needs to be copied a second time once the size is known.  (unlike `List<T>`, arrays cannot have extra space)
The same is true for async versions.

However, you may not want this function at all.
Unless you really need to get all of the data on the client, it will be much more efficient to use LINQ to entities to run SQL queries in the database.