# Calling subclass in an array of parent class occurs an error called "cannot reference a type through an expression" in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, class, subclass

I have a class called "Account".
Here are my codes:

```
// Account.cs
public partial class Account
{
    private Account.Credential _credential = new Account.Credential();

    public void Login(string UserID, string UserPW)
    {
        try
        {
            // do something

            _credential.CookieCollection = browser.CookieCollection;
            _credential.CookieContainer = browser.CookieContainer;
            _credential.UserID = "test";
            _credential.UserPW = "test";
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            throw err;
        }
    }
}

// Credential.cs
public partial class Account
{
    public class Credential
    {
        // Model
        public CookieCollection CookieCollection { get; set; }
        public CookieContainer CookieContainer { get; set; }
        public string UserID { get; set; }
        public string UserPW { get; set; }
    }
}

// Form1.cs
public void ABC()
{
    Account[] _account = new Account[2];
    _account[0].Login("myID", "myPW");

    Account.Credential _cred = _account[0].Credential; ---> I get an error.
}
```

But when I write a mothod call the Account class in array and call the sub class which is Credential, it gives me an error.

'Credential': cannot reference a type through an expression; try 'Account.Credential' instead.

Because, Login method is in Account Class I should have make an array of Account class. Not Credential class.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: `throw ex` is evil. http://stackoverflow.com/a/2999314/34397

Comment: You need to access an `Instance` member of Account class which holds the credentials. In your case `_credentials`. You need to make it public though.

Answer (score 2):

As the error is trying to tell you, the `Credential` type is a part of the `Account` *type*; not any single `Account` instance.

It makes no sense to refer to the type `myAccounts[42].Credential` or `mikesAccount.Credential`.

If you want to get that user's credential, you'll need to refer to a field or property of the `Account` class.
You could write `myAccounts[42]._credential`, except that `_credential` is private, so that will give a different error.
You should make a public, probably-read-only, property.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because `Account.Credential` is an internal type to `Account` and isn't used like how you're using it. What code is attempting to do would be similar to trying

```
var str = String;
```

You need to initialize an `Account.Credential`. A simple was is to use `new` inside Account's ctor or the `Login()` method.

I noticed you're going to run into further problems with your code - if you want to access the `Account.Credential` reference declared inside `Account`, you'll need to expose it through a method or change the access modifier.