# how to properly use: System.InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, exception, unity-game-engine

This is Unity C#

```
//...
    public static void Interupt(int Index, string Text){
        try{
            Change(Transforms[ Index ], Text);
        }
        catch{
            throw new System.InvalidOperationException("Index: " + Index + " Is too large should be less than: " + Transforms.Count); // points me here
        }
    }
}
```

ok this code points me to

```
throw, ...
```

how do I make it to point me to line where the function was called?

like:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class TestScript : MonoBehaviour {
    void Start(){
        SomeClass.Interupt(5, ""); // I want it to point me here
    }
}
```

THO I did try doing:

```
return throw new System.InvalidOperationException("Index: " + Index + "  Is too large should be less than: " + Transforms.Count);
```

but I get:

```
error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `throw'
```

witch is totally logical.

BUT what I can't figure out is how does Unity handle this things that it points us to functions and not throw lines?

I hope any of you has knowledge in Unity Engine

Comment: You need to read the entire stack trace.  Also, don't swallow the original exception; you're hiding all information about the actual problem.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/2999314/34397

Comment: hmmm @Slaks if I'm hiding with throw new, ... how would I point it to function witch is calling it instead of exception line?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the debugger to jump to the function that called `Interrupt` instead of jumping to Interrupt directly, you could just decorate the Interrupt method with the `DebuggerStepThroughAttribute`, i.e.

```
    [DebuggerStepThrough]
    public static void Interupt(int Index, string Text)
    {
        try
        {
            Change(Transforms[Index], Text);
        }
        catch
        {
            throw new System.InvalidOperationException("Index: " + Index + " Is too large should be less than: " + Transforms.Count); // points me here
        }
    }
```

If you want to analyze this programmatically, you have to use the call stack trace.

Comment: how do I do stack trace?

Comment: In the call stack trace, you only get a string that you then have to analyze by your own.

Comment: I get 2 errors: ** Assets/Scripts/SomeClass.cs(48,10): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `DebuggerStepThrough' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference? **

Comment: Assets/Scripts/SomeClass.cs(48,10): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `DebuggerStepThroughAttribute' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Comment: I'm sorry this is area witch completely I don't understand.

Comment: The DebuggerStepThroughAttribute is defined in the System.Diagnostics namespace of mscorlib, at least in .NET 4.0, but I guess it's the same in other versions.