# How to take an image of Exception "No messageBox"

Tags: c#, image, coded-ui-tests

I have the following code:

```
public void Method1()
{
    try
    {
        this.UIMap.abc(TestContext.DataRow["xxx"].ToString());
        this.UIMap.xyz(TestContext.DataRow["zzz"].ToString());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Image pic = this.UIMap.UItestingWindow.CaptureImage();
        pic.Save(@"C:\result.bmp");
        TestContext.AddResultFile(@"C:\result.bmp");
    }
```

How can I take an image of an `Exception` with "No messageBox"? 
If an error occurs, `Method2()` should be called.

Comment: **Never** write `throw ex;`.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/2999314/34397

Comment: Your question is extremely unclear.

Comment: basicly, I want to capture the error

Comment: So just check `ex.ToString()`.

Comment: No, google search is just an example I used to test if code moves to the public void Method2() if error occur.

Comment: forget the google part!!! I want to take the image of the error "catch (Exception ex)" and save it on C:\. But the code is not taking image of error.

Comment: Image pic = this.UIMap.UItestingWindow.CaptureImage(); is only taking picture of Window with no error displayed. allthough, when I use MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); right before Image pic = this.UIMap.UItestingWindow.CaptureImage(); it does show me the error.

Comment: Your question is unclear, what is it you want to save? What happens when you try to save? And what do you want to happen instead? Please [edit the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/21973229/edit) to add more details in.

Comment: The exception will only catch errors in your own program, not in the Internet Explorer process. If you want to automate web browser testing, have a look at ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286726.aspx ). This is an intermediate topic.

Comment: I wanted to an image of error, but for some reason the image is not capturing the error. It is only capturing the (application) image with no error display.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "Image of the error".

Comment: As far as the program is concerned, no error has occurred. You have captured it with the `catch` statement.

Comment: Are you sure your code even gets into the `catch` block? What does it see for `ex`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I'm helping, but here's how you can throw an exception and take an image of the the dialog box.

```
[TestMethod]
    public void CodedUITestMethod1()
    {
        WinWindow window = new WinWindow();
        window.SearchProperties[WinWindow.PropertyNames.Name] = "Error Window";
        WinButton okButton = new WinButton(window);
        okButton.SearchProperties[WinButton.PropertyNames.Name] = "OK";

        try
        {
            throw new Exception("Coded UI is throwing an exception.  No idea about the Internet explorer state.");
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error Window");
                }).Start();
            throw new Exception("An unexpected exception occurred in Coded UI",ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            Image pic = window.CaptureImage();
            pic.Save(@"C:\result.bmp");
            Mouse.Click(okButton);
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The whole desktop including the wanted message box can be obtained with:

```
Image pic = UITestControl.Desktop.CaptureImage();
```