# Catching an Exception and rethrowing in C# - can it keep its type?

Tags: c#, exception

We have a business-critical bit of legacy code, and the methods are relatively large and the code is a mess. Without a test framework and it being so critical our debugging abilities are limited. The logging messages are not useful - "object not set to an instance of an object"... somewhere in 500 lines of code that call other methods. This is because the method body is one big try/catch with specific exceptions being caught.

I want to propose that we address this with better error logging but I want to minimise my impact on the method. I need it to carry on as normal, because it is business critical. As such, people are scared to touch it so I need to check my understanding before I put the idea forward. As I say, I cannot just make a change and test it myself without writing a test harness. Which I don't have time to do due to firefighting, and it being last thing on a Friday.

I think a good way to do this is to insert smaller try/catch blocks inside the method body to catch all exceptions, log some USEFUL information, then rethrow to the specific catch handlers below.

```
public int SomeFunc()
{
    try
    {
        // many lines of code

        // I want to wrap this call that gives us problems
        try
        {
            BrittleFunc(arg1, arg2, ..., arg15);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // Log the params for repro in unit test and then rethrow
            Log(args);
            throw;
        }

        // many more lines of code

    }
    catch(CustomException1 e)
    {
        // Do something
    }
    // more...
    catch(CustomException9 e)
    {
        // Do something
    }
    return someInt;
}
```

In my inner try/catch I COULD write specific catch handlers that match those at the bottom, but that will look messy.

If I catch CustomException2 inside a catch(Exception e) and rethrow, will it end up in catch(CustomException2 e) ?

Comment: What is the purpose of the inner try/catch? In general, you should log at the highest possible level of your program.

Comment: You can just run the program you already have *once* and find out.  It would have taken you a lot less time than you spent writing this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do that. Inside your first catch, the exception is simply treaded as the base `Exception` but when you rethrow it the next catch will catch it as it's real type.

When you rethrow the exception please use `throw;` not `thrown ex;` [see here why](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2999314/34397)