# What class throws the exception in the end?

Tags: c#, exception

I have two methods:

```
public void MethodOne() 
{

    try {
    MethodTwo();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
    Log.Message("Something went wrong);
    throw;
    }
}

public void MethodTwo()
{

    try {
    // Some logic that fails
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
    throw ex;
    }
}
```

I'm calling MethodTwo from MethodOne. If a exception is thrown in MethodTwo. Will the program terminate after the exception has been handled there or will it bubble up to MethodOne and be catched there aswell?

Comment: why not just try it out using your debugger?

Comment: For clarification, MethodTwo does not handle the exception, it throws it. Actually it throws a new one without the original's stack trace. If you debug you will see it bubbles up and you land in the catch block of MethodOne.

Comment: What prevents you from hitting F5 and trying it out? Also, what do you think would happen to error handling such as logging if applications would terminate on the first `throw` they encounter?

Comment: You may find this helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/730250/is-there-a-difference-between-throw-and-throw-ex

Answer (score 0):

The exception will be catched and rethrown in `MethodTwo` and then catched and rethrown again in `MethodOne`.

Whether the application will terminate depends on how and where you call `MethodOne` and whether you catch the exception when calling `MethodOne` or further up the call chain.

Note that `throw ex` [resets the stack trace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2999298/difference-between-throw-and-throw-new-exception) and should be avoided.

Answer (score -1):

The program will be terminated in MethodOne.

You can understand more from this article. [Throw and Re-throw Exceptions in C#](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/throw-re-throw-expectations)

Be aware, by throwing the exception will destroy the stack trace information!