# Is there any technical reason to write a catch block containing only a throw statement?

Tags: c#, exception

Disclaimer: It is well known that `catch (ex) { throw ex; }` [is bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/881473/87698). This question is **not** about that.

---

While digging through Microsoft reference sources, I noticed the following pattern in [a lot of methods](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/Security/SQLMembershipProvider.cs,a4842c55252c3c3e):

```
try {
    ...
} catch {
    throw;
}
```

No logging, no debugging code—just a plain simple `catch { throw; }`.

Since, obviously, the guys at Microsoft should be fairly proficient in the use of C#, what could be the point of doing that instead of just omitting the catch block (and the try statement) altogether? **Is there a technical reason for coding like this, or is it purely a stylistic choice?**

**Note**: I don't know if it is relevant, but all such instances I could find also contain a `try-finally` block nested inside the `try` clause of the `try-catch` block.

Comment: The obvious is to allow breakpoints to be set without altering the source and where you want to break in that method on any exception. Which is discussed in [one of the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1443543/15498) to the question you already linked.

Comment: *Microsoft should be fairly proficient in the use of C#* Primarily opinion based ;)

Comment: That force all relevant `finally` blocks to be executed.

Comment: @PetSerAl `finally` blocks execute regardless of the presence of a `catch` block.

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2728661/7923571)

Comment: @JamesThorpe AFAIK, .NET do not run any `finally` or `fault` blocks until it find a `catch` to handle exception. Which mean if there are no catch block and exception escape thread root method, then .NET not obligated to run any `finally`/`fault` blocks at all. Also, order of exception filters and `finally` blocks may be relevant if `finally` block do security related staff, like revert impersonation.

Comment: @PetSerAl: You are wrong. A finally block does not require a catch block to run. There are circumstances where you can't rely on a finally block to be run but those are abnormal things like pulling out the power cable on the computer. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/try-finally for an example of a try...finally which by your thinking would be a pointless construct.

Comment: Looking at the answers so far they both seem to be speculating on why somebody might write that code which is inherently subjective. It feels like it is currently "Primarily Opinion Based". I'm wondering if it could be modified slightly to ask for specific technical reasons for it but then the answer I suspect is slightly trivial.

Comment: @Chris [C# specification](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/spec/exceptions.md#how-exceptions-are-handled): Once a matching catch clause is found, the system prepares to transfer control to the first statement of the catch clause. Before execution of the catch clause begins, the system first executes, in order, any finally clauses that were associated with try statements more nested that than the one that caught the exception.
If no matching catch clause is found, one of two things occurs:

Comment: If the search for matching catch clauses reaches the code that initially started the thread, then execution of the thread is terminated. The impact of such termination is **implementation-defined**.

Comment: @Chris Also read your own link: However, if the exception is unhandled, execution of the finally block is dependent on how the exception unwind operation is triggered. ... Usually, when an unhandled exception ends an application, whether or not the finally block is run is not important. However, if you have statements in a finally block that must be run even in that situation, one solution is to add a catch block to the try-finally statement.

Comment: @PetSerAl Actually, that's a really good point.  Especially when **taken in conjunction with the code that the OP linked to**.  These try/catches are wrapped around try/finally blocks.  I think that would form the basis of a good answer.

Comment: @Heinzi Is it the case that in all the cases you've found this code structure in the reference source, that they're wrapped around a try/finally?  The first couple I found in the file you linked to certainly are.

Comment: @PetSerAl: Well that will teach me to think I understand something and not read it properly! Thanks for the illumination. :)

Comment: @JamesThorpe: Now that you mention it: Yes, all of them are wrapped around a try/finally. Interesting! If PetSerAl's assumption is correct, this would be a very interesting answer.

Comment: @Heinzi May be worth bumping this question with an edit showing that actually rather than asking about the `try{}catch{throw;}` pattern, it turns out it's more specifically the `try{try{}finally{}}catch{throw;}` pattern? I've had a quick look around, and haven't (yet) found another question about it

Comment: @JamesThorpe: Wouldn't that be more appropriate in the answer? *"`catch {throw;}` makes sense if the try block contains an inner try-finally block, because... /stuff about the C# spec and finalizers/..."*. I don't want to rule out a priori that there might be other possible explanations and the inner try-finally-clause is just a coincidence. I will add a note about your observation, though.

Comment: Maybe - definitely worth noting how it's used in the code you read in the Q though as I think it makes it more tangible than perhaps something that's more opinion based

Comment: @JamesThorpe: True, I've added a note. I don't want to expand the code example with the inner try-finally block, because I'm *sure* that this would cause a lot of people to (1) quickly glance at the question and (2) add a completely useless answer explaining the use of `try-finally` inside `try-catch`. ;-)

Comment: Is there any way to figure out if this "design" is all from the same author/developer or maybe from the same "architect" (whomever does code reviews and is allowed to commit overriding changes)? Maybe this person has a bias towards this design because it is their preferred way of debugging or testing edge case scenarios (exceptions)? Too bad there is no way to see a commit history....

Comment: @Amit - It **is** a bad practice. The whole call stack is reset and you lose information that can be vital to debugging the original reason why/where the exception occurred in the first place. Even with a 3rd party class library you should not use `throw ex;`. If you want to abstract the Exception in your own type then throw a new exception and pass the original in as the inner exception.

Comment: @Amit That's the whole point. By clobbering the stack trace, `throw ex;` effectively *doesn't* doesn't throw the original exception that happened. To rethrow the original exception that happened, just use `throw;`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As [C# Specification](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/spec/exceptions.md#how-exceptions-are-handled) describes:

> When an exception occurs, the system searches for the nearest `catch` clause that can handle the exception, as determined by the run-time type of the exception. First, the current method is searched for a lexically enclosing `try` statement, and the associated `catch` clauses of the `try` statement are considered in order. If that fails, the method that called the current method is searched for a lexically enclosing `try` statement that encloses the point of the call to the current method. This search continues until a `catch` clause is found that can handle the current exception, by naming an exception class that is of the same class, or a base class, of the run-time type of the exception being thrown. A `catch` clause that doesn't name an exception class can handle any exception.
>
> Once a matching `catch` clause is found, the system prepares to transfer control to the first statement of the `catch` clause. Before execution of the `catch` clause begins, the system first executes, in order, any `finally` clauses that were associated with `try` statements more nested that than the one that caught the exception.

in case of exception runtime first looks for `catch` clause that can handle it, which involve executing any associated exception filters. Undiscriminating `catch` block interrupt that search and make all nested `finally` blocks to be executed immediately.

That can be useful when you want to prevent caller from executing arbitrary code (in form of exception filter) before `finally` block. For example, when `finally` block affect security context of current thread.

Also, if exception will not be caught by any `catch` clause, then it will lead to thread termination. And in that case C# Specification did not provide any guaranty, that any `finally` block will be executed at all.

> If the search for matching catch clauses reaches the code that initially started the thread, then execution of the thread is terminated. The impact of such termination is implementation-defined.

Answer (score 12):

It affects when exception filters run.

Given

```
void f() {
  using (var x = AcquireResource()) {
    x.DoSomething();
    x.DoSomethingElse();
  }
}
```

versus

```
void f() {
  try {
    using (var x = AcquireResource()) {
      x.DoSomething();
      x.DoSomethingElse();
    }
  } catch {
    throw;
  }
}
```

with

```
void g() {
  try {
    f();
  } catch (Exception ex) when (h()) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

The first version of `f` would allow the filter `h()` to be called before `x` got disposed. The second version of `f` ensures that `x` is disposed before external code is run.

In the code you link to, `SqlConnectionHolder` is used a lot, and `catch { throw; }` blocks are all around the use of `SqlConnectionHolder`.

Answer (score -2):

The code you linked is actually a very good example.

In my eyes, one should only use *try catch* blocks when dealing with things outside of their control, like file systems, external things basically.

In the code you linked the *try catch* is around the database stuff.

What this means is that by using this way of coding, they make sure there are no leaks, no connections remain open.

If anything goes wrong, such as wrong connection string, missing tables, whatever, the code is going to continue to execute, it will  gracefully close the connection as shown in the *finally* block and it will finally throw meaning it will allow the client of that code to get the proper exception, get the entire stack as well and let them decide what to do when that happens.

To be honest I quite like what they did there.

Comment: Check the comments.This isn't about leaks or normal exception handling. It's about the behaviour of `try/finally` in unexpected situations.

Comment: I am not responding to comments, I am responding to the question the OP asked. If that is no longer meaningful then the question needs to be edited to reflect that.

Comment: Check. The. Comments. Your answer is wrong. The OP is asking why `try/finally` is wrapped in `try/catch`. The answer is that unhandled exceptions may *never* run the code in `finally`

Comment: @AndreiDragotoniu: OP here. I appreciate you answering the question, but the question was specifically about why someone would use `try ... catch { throw; }` instead of just `...`. I am afraid your answer does not address that at all (even if we don't consider the comments).

Comment: In any case, in order to close connections and resources you use `try/finally`, not `try/catch`. The question (and related [C# docs, specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/try-finally)) though shows that `finally` isn't always enough