# TRY-CATCH relative to USING

Tags: c#

I've been implementing TRY-CATCH relative to USING like the following example:

```
private void someDatabaseMethod(string userName) {

    try {

        using(var conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
        using(var comm = new SqlCommand()) {
            comm.Connection = conn;
            comm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            comm.CommandText = string.Concat(@"SELECT UserID FROM xxx WHERE UserName = '", userName,@"'");
            conn.Open();
            object x = comm.ExecuteScalar();
            UserID = (x==null)? 0: (int)x;
        }
    } catch(Exception) {
        throw;
    }
}
```

I've just seen this [MSDN EXAMPLE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx) which seems to point towards the TRY-CATCH being within the USING. So my example would look like the following:

```
private void someDatabaseMethod(string userName) {

        using(var conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
        using(var comm = new SqlCommand()) {
            comm.Connection = conn;
            comm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            comm.CommandText = string.Concat(@"SELECT UserID FROM xxx WHERE UserName = '", userName,@"'");

            try {

               conn.Open();
               object x = comm.ExecuteScalar();
               UserID = (x==null)? 0: (int)x;

            } catch(Exception) {
               throw;
            }
        }
}
```

Is this a more efficient layout? If so, why?

---

**EXTRA ADDITIONAL NOTE**

The reason for the `TRY-CATCH` is to re-throw the exception so that I bubble it up to the next level - so I'd like to have a `CATCH` somewhere in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TRY-CATCH I use in `using` only if I want to LOG Exception or it I have transaction - to rollback it in except block. 
using is translated by compiler in TRY-FINALLY - you can check it with IL Disassembler (ildasm.exe) or reflector to release your disposable resources. 
so that 
`using` is equivalent to :

```
try 
{
 //do job
} 
finally
{
  Resource.Dispose()
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It depends on your goals. If you want to do something with command or connection in catch block, then it should be within using.

Comment: +1 for the classic "it depends"

Answer (score 2):

If you just throw the catched exception, the try-catch block isn't necessary at all. The using will dispose the conenction and command properly.

Comment: The reason for the `TRY-CATCH` is to re-throw the exception so that I can bubble it up to the next level - so I'd like to have a `CATCH` somewhere in the code.

Answer (score 2):

Second one is more efficient. For first one; you can not access connection object from catch block, and can not close it. Also if you was using a transaction over this connection, you could not rollback the transaction when any error occurs...

Comment: +1 for first one - if it errors on `conn.Open();` what happens first: will the using deal with the problem and free resources ? or will it go to CATCH before using has a chance to garbage collect?

Answer (score 0):

- Don't catch exceptions you cannot handle at this place.
- catch{throw;} is of no use except adding complexity
- catch and handle exceptions as near at the exception source as you are able to handle them

[Read extensive discussion here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1697216/the-difference-between-try-catch-throw-and-try-catche-throw-e)

Comment: catch{throw;} bubbles the exception up to a higher level and it is dealt with there

Comment: And therefore catch-throw is for nothing as the exception will "bubble" up also without this construct.