# Try Catch Finally nested behaviour with exception

Tags: c#, exception

So I was wondering about the behaviour of a nested `try-catch-finally` blocks.

What I mean is, what if inside the first `finally` block, we have another `try-catch-finally` blocks and a exception happens in the inner `finally` block??

Is the exception going to be propagated? And is it going to be caught somewhere?

Where should I catch the exception? In the inner `finally` block or if it's propagated should I catch it from the upper code?

Example:

```
static bool Func()
{
    try
    {}
    catch
    {}
    finally
    {
        try
        {}
        catch
        {}
        finally
        {
           throw new ApplicationException();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No I'm asking about an exception in the inner finally block @BenReich

Comment: And no, @Anirudh, I'm asking about a nested one.

Comment: the inner finally block's exception would propagate out of the containing finally block and would be handled at the higher level..So excetion thrown in inner finally block would go outward until it finds a specific catch block at higher  level or it would throw the exception if none is found

Comment: You could easily write code and test your hypothesis any way you want. This question is rightfully closed, there are plenty of resources on this site and elsewhere that describe the behavior, and you can test to discover and confirm those behaviors as well. Do more research.

Comment: as i said for your given example there's no catch block for that exception and so it would not be catch'ed..remember all other outer finally block would not be executed further..

Comment: So or I put a try with a catch inside for the exception or I put a try for all the code and the catch under

Answer (score -1):

Depends. You can handle the exception in your inner exception, but if you don't want to handle it, you can just THROW it so the outer Try Catch will 'receive' the exception.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1697216/the-difference-between-try-catch-throw-and-try-catche-throw-e) for more detailed example :

Comment: How is the outer Try Cartch going to read the exception if the exception happens in a finally??