# Change catch (COMException ce) to catch (COMException)

Tags: c#, com, exception

I have the following code:

```
       try
       {
           retval = axNTLXRemote.IsUnitPresent(_servers[0].IPAddress, 1, _servers[0].RemotePort, _servers[0].CommFailDelay * 1000);
       }
       catch (COMException ce)
       {
            throw ce;
       }
```

Which gives me the followig warning which I want to get rid of:

**CA2200 : Microsoft.Usage : 'Connect()' rethrows a caught exception and specifies it explicitly as an argument. Use 'throw' without an argument instead, in order to preserve the stack location where the exception was initially raised.**

I have read the following [The difference between try/catch/throw and try/catch(e)/throw e](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1697216/the-difference-between-try-catch-throw-and-try-catche-throw-e) and I understand that the 'throw ce; will reset the stack trace and make it appear as if the exception was thrown from that function.

I want to simply change it to a 'throw' instead of a 'throw ce' which will get rid of the warning.

1. What is the difference in the following catches:

   ```
      catch (COMException ce)
      {
           throw;
      }
   ```

   and

   ```
      catch (COMException)
      {
           throw;
      }
   ```
2. Do I only need to have 'COMException ce' if I wish to somehow use the ce variable?
3. Also, when I perform a 'throw' or 'throw ce', is it the calling function that will handle or catch it?? I'm a little unclear about this.

Comment: Good advice.  Better advice is to just get rid of try/catch, it doesn't do anything useful.

Comment: I have inherited a project which is riddled with try/catches so I'm trying to tidy up warnings etc.  I can't get rid of all of them at this stage.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference in both cases, but only when exception variable should be used for stack/message etc.

So:

```
catch(ComException);
```

and

```
catch(ComException ex);
```

statements will produce similar MSIL, except local variable for ComException object:

```
.locals init ([0] class [mscorlib]System.Exception ex)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure someone will jump in with an uber-technical answer, but in my experience the answer to your first two questions is that there is no difference, and as you stated you'd only include `ce` if you intended to use it to write the stack trace to a log or display the message to the user or similar.

The `throw` will send the exception up the chain. That may be the calling method or, if your method has several nested try/catch blocks, it will send the exception to the next try/catch block that the current try/catch block is nested within.

Here are a couple good resources to check out if you want to read further on the subject:

- [Exception Handling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229005%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)
- [Design Guidelines for Exceptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229014%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: So if I look further up the chain (Or for another nested catch) and see nothing else that is using the ce variable then I know that I can safely remove it????

Answer (score 1):

1. The only difference is that with `catch (COMException ce)`, you are assigning the exception to a variable, thereby letting you access it within the `catch` block. Other than that, it is in every way identical.
2. I'm not sure what the question is here. If you want to access the exception object, you must give it a variable name in the `catch` clause.
3. No matter how or where an exception is thrown, the exception will bubble up through the call stack to the closest `catch` block that matches.

Here's an example.

```
void Method1()
{
    try
    {
        Method2();
    }
    catch // this will catch *any* exception
    {
    }
}

void Method2()
{
    try
    {
        Method3();
    }
    catch (COMException ex) // this will catch only COMExceptions and exceptions that derive from COMException
    {
    }
}

void Method3()
{
    // if this code were here, it would be caught in Method2
    throw new COMException();


    // if this code were here, it would be caught in Method1
    throw new ApplicationException();
}
```