# try{} catch(Exception e){} VS try{} catch(Exception e){ throw;} - What the difference?

Tags: c#, anti-patterns

I got here that the next code is **anti-pattern**. Is it right?

```
try
{
//something
} 
catch(Exception e)
{
//something
}
```

And why better to use

```
try
{
//something
} 
catch(Exception e)
{
 //something
 throw;
}
```

?

I got that second variant is using for re-throwing exception (logging for example), but if I need re-throw the same exception why not use the next code?

```
try
{
//something
} 
catch(Exception e)
{
 //something
 throw e;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1697216/the-difference-between-try-catch-throw-and-try-catche-throw-e?rq=1

Comment: You don't keep the stacktrace (f.e. the original line number) if you `throw e;` instead of `throw;`. The new stacktrace shows your empty `catch` block which is undesirable. An empty catch is bad practise anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will re-throw the same exception and keep the stack trace.  This will make debugging easier.

```
catch(Exception e)
{
 //something
 throw;
}
```

This will rethrow the exception, but you'll lose the stack trace.

```
catch(Exception e)
{
 //something
 throw e;
}
```

This will silently swallow the exception.  You only want to do this when you're catching a specific exception rather than `Exception`.  You should generally have a good reason for doing so.

```
try
{
//something
} 
catch(Exception e)
{
//something
}
```

Comment: Essentially, you should never throw an exception that you have caught, by name. You should either throw a new exception (optionally including the caught exception as an inner exception) or _rethrow_ using `throw` without an operand.

Comment: You've pointed out the difference between examples 2 and 3, which is already addressed in the other question linked in the comments. Asker is asking the difference between 1 and 2 first, and only asking about 2 and 3 in the context of trying to understand why 2 is better than 1.